# CSS table-cell does not work in Chrome or FireFox?

Tags: css, css-tables

I have the following code -- which renders (oddly enough) correctly in IE, but not in Chrome or FireFox, see:

[http://jsfiddle.net/eS34U/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/eS34U/13/)

```
.btn_group_fill { display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%; }
.btn_group_fill .btn { display:table-cell;float:none; }
```

Basically the element with the "btn_group btn_group_fill" should span the entire width -- which it does in IE -- but NOT in chrome or firefox -- obviously, I am missing some CSS element (or combination); if anyone with some insight can spot my error, I would appreciate it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is specific to the `button` element. Presumably the browsers have different takes on how these should be presented. If you change them to `span` or `div` it renders as expected.

```
<div class="btn_group btn_group_fill">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn_primary">Group Button 1</div>
    <div type="button" class="btn btn_default">Group Button 2</div>
    <div type="button" class="btn btn_default">Group Button 3</div>
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eS34U/16/)

Also, the border-collapse property may be useful here if you want the 'cells' to share borders.

```
border-collapse: collapse; /* is 'separate' by default */
```